# Saving a toggled class Div (with local storage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have an example of a basic classtoggle with a `div` but can I make it so the "active `class`" can stay switched with a refresh/re-open. Could this be done?

```js
function myfunc(div) {
  var className = div.getAttribute("class");
  if(className=="normal") {
    div.className = "active";
  }
  else{
    div.className = "normal";
  }
}
```

```css
.normal /*Default*/
{width:25%; height:25%; background: #ffeb00;}

.active /*Switch*/
{width:25%; height:25%; background: #ff00e2;}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div" class="normal" onclick="myfunc(this)"></div>
        <script src=".jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank You for all future Answers.

Comment: Um, what have you tried? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Comment: did you actually tried using localstorage?

Comment: Yes a thew times actually, but it keeps canceling the actual toggle formula, so I can't tell if it's working or not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use the `localStorage` to hold the last class

[**try jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/farhadB/noL8hjek/)

```
 $("#div").addClass(localStorage.getItem('ClassName')) ;

 $("#div").on("click",function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('active')){
           $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("normal");
           localStorage.setItem('ClassName', 'normal');
       }
       else{
           $(this).removeClass("normal").addClass("active");
           localStorage.setItem('ClassName', 'active');
       }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this, haven't tested but this will get you on the right track (note that snippet cannot run on stack overflow due to being sandboxed)

```js
function localStorageExists() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

if (localStorageExists()) {
  myfunc(document.getElementById('div'));
}

function myfunc(div) {
  var className = div.getAttribute("class");
  if (className == "normal" || (localStorageExists() && localStorage.getItem('someKey') == 'active')) {
    div.className = "active";
    localStorage.setItem('someKey', 'active');
  } else if (className == "active" || (localStorageExists() && localStorage.getItem('someKey') == 'normal')) {
    div.className = "normal";
    localStorage.setItem('someKey', 'normal');
  }
}
```

```css
.normal
/*Default*/

{
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background: #ffeb00;
}

.active
/*Switch*/

{
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background: #ff00e2;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div" class="normal" onclick="myfunc(this)"></div>
  <script src=".jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```